# How do i make a nested FileInfo List?

Tags: c#, winforms

What i want to do is to get all the directories and each directory the files inside and add it to a List. The List should look like this for example:

In index[0] {[fileinfo list and all the files here]}

So in each index I will have the directory and inside all the files of this directory.

I tried to do:

```
private void getfiles()
{
    List<List<FileInfo>> fileList = new List<List<FileInfo>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]);
        fileList.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.Length > 0));
    }
    file_array = fileList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
    //file_array = fileList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime).Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

I changed the `List<FileInfo>` to `List<List<FileInfo>>`, so a List in a List.

So in the end if i have 5 directories on the hard disk the List will have 5 indexs and in each index there will be a List with the files of the directory.

EDIT**

This is the timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {     
        //this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        for (int i = 0; i < file_array.Length; i++)
        {

        }
        if (leave == true)
        {
            pb.Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
        }
        else
        {
            pbs[0].Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
        }
        file_indxs = file_indxs + 1;
        if (file_indxs >= file_array.Length)
        {
            file_indxs = 0;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I have 8 pictureBoxes I create them in the form1 constructor. 
In this case in the timer tick event I assign the images to pbs[0] its the first pictureBox.

What I need to do is to use the nested list and assign each directory with the files inside to a pictureBox.
So the first index in the nested list the files there should be assign to the first pictureBox pbs[0] then index 1 to pbs[1] and so on.

So if the nested list have 5 indexes it should be assigned to 5 pictureBoxes.

Instead assigning all the images to pbs[0] that's why I did the nested list.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is how to do it with the FileInfo. I did it once long time ago with String. But since i want to sort the files im not sure how to do it in this case. I changed the FileInfo List to be nested list but im not sure how to use it from there.

Comment: Somehow it's still hard to tell what the actual problem and your intention is. A lot of information but no question. I think it would help if you could narrow down your actual problem to 1-2 sentences and a (more specific) question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group all the files by **directory**. There are some ways to do so, for example each time you prepare to enumerate files of a directory, just create a new `List<FileInfo>`, enumerate files and add them to the new list, each newly created list will be added to the root `List<List<FileInfo>>` (which can be converted to an array if you want). However I would like to use this approach which will modify your code as less as possible:

```
private void getfiles() {
  List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
  for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++) {
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]);
    fileList.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(x => x.Length > 0));
  }
  file_array = fileList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.DirectoryName)
                       .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.FullName).ToList())
                       .ToArray();
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

**NOTE**: The `file_array` will have type `List<string>[]` (an array of `List<string>`). Your problem looks like still unclear to me with the involvement of `timer1`, but this should solve your question (not your whole problem). You should ask another question for related issue. This answer just **answers to the question** you gave.

Comment: King King when i tried now your new answer im getting an error on the line fileList.AddRange: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>>)' has some invalid arguments And another error on this line: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>>'

Comment: King and also an error on the line : file_array = fileList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime) on the CreationTime: Error 3 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'CreationTime' and no extension method 'CreationTime' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DoronMuzar updated, I copied and pasted your code without noticing about the declaration of `fileList`, it should be `List<FileInfo>`